# Shell scripting

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

i am new in linux and using ubuntu'10.10'...i basically want to know as what is the significance of learning shell....????...i googled but max time i find tutorial but didnot get any satisfactory answers...

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to automate small tasks where using real programming languages is overkill (e.g. batch convert files, rip DVD chapters, synchronize directories, ...) shell scripts often are invaluable.

Moreover, a lot of "plumbing" in the system is done with shell scripts (e.g. daemons start/stop scripts, event scripts), so knowing at least how to read them often can give you a grasp on how some parts of the system work under the hood, and give you a clue about where the problem can lie in case of malfunctions; knowing how to write them can also be useful if you need to customize the system in some way.

Comment: @coolmego: to a certain extent. The "big stuff" (kernel & co) is compiled, but there are a lot of scripts that make the system work, and those can be edited (if you need it and you know what you're doing).

Comment: Let me make it more elaborate...in linux a directory doesnot mounts by itself..so can we make such scripts which can mount the disks while booting????

Comment: @coolmego: sure (you may make it an `init.d` script), but you can already do it with `fstab`. And we're going off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

That is a nice question to ask. The fact is that studying shell script help you to do a lot of tasks, (well it helped me ). I used shell script whenever i had to perform more than one Linux commands one by one and sometimes when I had to run jobs over and over again with same pattern. Shell really helps in doing such tasks. 
And off the syllabus, studying shell for tasks made me more familiar with the OS and commands.